# Is there way way to pause an animation for a few seconds without JavaScript?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a multiline typewriter effect that had pauses on punctuation, e.g. commas, full stops.

My current solution uses a ton of spans, and looks horrific.

Is there a way to pause an animation without js, or maybe there’s another solution to my problem?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Can you please put some code for us to use?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @html_coder I have no useful code currently. My old code that generated the spans solution is pointless, as I would like a different way to solve my problem

Comment: If you cannot use spans I see no way of helping without a fully JS solution, plodding through the text doing the animation with JS timing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a css animation play state.

[w3schools example](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-play-state.php)

Its hard to give you a better example without seeing your code but hopefully you can use w3's example to incorporate into yours. Good luck!

Comment: I know about play state, but how do I control it not using JavaScript? I mean, I can’t pause the keyframes within the animation because then I can’t unpause it, right?

Comment: a play state is a css property. there are a variety of conditions of sorts that you can use in css. some of the most common used are ones that apply different styles based on the screen width (to determine if user is mobile or desktop). just find a trigger that you like.

what is the reason to avoid js tho? what machine is this intended to be ran on?

Comment: using the pause/play example. you will prob want click events. another css feature. Ideally you would just use JS and have an event listner but whatever. here is an article on pointer events using only css.

https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/17/css-click-events/

other css things for you to read over:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events